# Что значит <> (вычитал в книге)?

Tags: псевдокод

Из книги:
Пример псевдокода правильно реструктурированной проверки условия

```
while ( i < MAX_ELEMENTS )
 if ( item[ i ] <> 0 ) then
```

Не пойму что значит `<>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<>` - Означает *"не равно"*. Синтаксис похож на паскалевский.
В вашем случае: если `item[i]` не равен `0`, то выполнить какие-то действия.

Comment: Это значит либо меньше, либо больше. `Не равно` пишется так `!=`. Но в конечном итоге это эквивалентно. В языках где есть знак `!` используется в качестве `not`, принято `!=`. А где нет, там `<>`, что бы не портить язык в целом. Где-то используются оба варианта.